# Does position in array enumConstants from Class, correspondes to ordinal value of enum?

Tags: java, enums

I designed a generic method, to read/write Set of Enum values as BigInteger

My original implementation

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Set<T> asList(BigInteger integer, Class<T> targetClass) {
    Set<T> enums = new HashSet<T>();
    // Step 0. Sanity check
    if (targetClass == null || integer == null || !targetClass.isEnum())
        return enums;
    // Step 1. Checking each value of target class
    T[] values = targetClass.getEnumConstants();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (integer.testBit(i))
            enums.add(values[i]);
    }
    // Step 3. Returning final enums
    return enums;
}
```

But, I switched to :

```
  public static <T extends Enum<T>> Set<T> asSet(BigInteger integer, Class<T> targetClass) {
    Set<T> enums = new HashSet<T>();
    // Step 0. Sanity check
    if (targetClass == null || integer == null || !targetClass.isEnum())
        return enums;
    // Step 1. Checking each value of target class
    T[] values = targetClass.getEnumConstants();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        T value = values[i];
        if (integer.testBit(value.ordinal()))
            enums.add(value);
    }
    // Step 3. Returning final enums
    return enums;
}
```

I've done so because of Enum.ordinal description in documentation:

```
 * Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position
 * in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned
 * an ordinal of zero).
```

So basically, first value might not always be 0.

***In which cases, or on which JVM's does enum initial value is not 0?***

Comment: How do you get from "where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero" to "first value might not always be 0"?

Comment: Misread it. Now I see my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say `So basically, first value might not always be 0.` how did you come to this conclusion?

The first enum constant always have a ordinal of 0. Of course if you change the order or add a new constant it will change for the same element. Which is why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the documentation. I read of zero as or zero, my bad.